# Opening KMZ files using QGIS

Tags: qgis, kmz

I am using the KML tools pluggin to import kmz files but I get:
"Failed to open file
Failed to open file
Execution failed after 0.01 seconds"

What could be causing this error?

Comment: rename .kmz to .zip and unzip that file there will be a .kml in the extracted folder along with a doc folder if images are used.